# Dynamic module feature checklist

Tags: jquery, list, dynamic

I'm trying to make some sort of dynamic checklist using jQuery, but am running into some issues which I can't seem to solve due to my complete lack of scripting skills. The current state of the code can be found below.

The basic idea is that there is a set of features attached to "module-1", while "module-2" has the same features as "module-1", but with some extra as well, so the "module-1" features should still be visible when "module-2" is selected. So far I've only been able to get the features for each module to highlight separately, but not together.

Important detail: I wanted to keep the script as flexible as possible. It's very much possible that there will be 3 or 4 modules in the future, always adding to the features of the previous module.

How would one go ahead and get this done?

Thanks in advance!

```js
var module_group = $('.module-group');

$(module_group).each(function() {
  var module_box = $(this).children('.module-toggle'); 
  $(module_box).click(function() {
    $(this).parent('.module-group').children('.module-toggle').removeClass('module-toggle--on');
    $(this).addClass('module-toggle--on');           
    if ($(this).hasClass('module-toggle--on')) { 
      var data_value = $(this).attr('data-id');
      
      $(this).parent().children('.module-features').find('li').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass(data_value)) {
          $(this).addClass('checked');
        } else {
          $(this).removeClass('checked');
        }
      });
    };
  });
});
```

```css
.checked {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="module-group">
  <div class="module-toggle module-toggle--on" data-id="module-1">
    Module 1
  </div>
  <div class="module-toggle module-toggle--on" data-id="module-2">
    Module 2
  </div>
  <div class="module-features">
    <ul>
      <li class="module-1">Module 1 feature</li>
      <li class="module-1">Module 1 feature</li>
      <li class="module-1">Module 1 feature</li>
      <li class="module-2">Module 2 feature</li>
      <li class="module-2">Module 2 feature</li>
      <li class="module-2">Module 2 feature</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `data-attributes`? If you need to select elements that have certain features you can put those features in a `data-features` attribute and then inside your click function to loop and check.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

Changes: I have added a line which removes all `checked` classes from the toggles first. There was never any at this level before, but I will be adding them just below:

```
$(".module-toggle").removeClass('checked');
```

Now none of the module toggles are higlighted. Then I have added a line which adds the `checked` class to the toggle which was clicked, while `this` is still the toggle itself, and not the children, when iterating those

```
$(this).addClass('checked');
```

This is all you need to change. The selectors of the module features could just skip the part `(this).parent().children` and start with `$('.module-features')`, with the same result, but it works like it is too.

```js
var module_group = $('.module-group');

$(module_group).each(function() {
  var module_box = $(this).children('.module-toggle'); 
  $(module_box).click(function() {
    $(this).parent('.module-group').children('.module-toggle').removeClass('module-toggle--on');
    $(this).addClass('module-toggle--on');           
    if ($(this).hasClass('module-toggle--on')) { 
      var data_value = $(this).attr('data-id');
      $(".module-toggle").removeClass('checked');
      $(this).addClass('checked');
      $(this).parent().children('.module-features').find('li').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass(data_value)) {
          $(this).addClass('checked');
        } else {
          $(this).removeClass('checked');
        }
      });
    };
  });
});
```

```css
.checked {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="module-group">
  <div class="module-toggle module-toggle--on" data-id="module-1">
    Module 1
  </div>
  <div class="module-toggle module-toggle--on" data-id="module-2">
    Module 2
  </div>
  <div class="module-toggle module-toggle--on" data-id="module-3">
    Module 3
  </div>
  <div class="module-features">
    <ul>
      <li class="module-1">Module 1 feature</li>
      <li class="module-1">Module 1 feature</li>
      <li class="module-1">Module 1 feature</li>
      <li class="module-2">Module 2 feature</li>
      <li class="module-2">Module 2 feature</li>
      <li class="module-2">Module 2 feature</li>
      <li class="module-3">Module 3 feature</li>
      <li class="module-3">Module 3 feature</li>
      <li class="module-3">Module 3 feature</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, I added a third module, just to show it works.

Answer (score 0):

Streamlined the code with the following behavior:

- Click a inactive `.module-toggle` and the last matching `.module-features li` and all previous `li` will be highlighted.
- If an active `.module-toggle` is clicked all `li` are unhighlighted.
- An extra module was added to show it is easily expandable (No modification to jQuery code needed).

---

### Demo

```js
$('.module-toggle').on('click', function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  var last = $('.module-features .' + id + ':last');
  if ($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
    $('.module-toggle').removeClass('checked');
    $('.module-features li').removeClass('checked');
  } else {
    $('.module-toggle').removeClass('checked');
    $(this).addClass('checked');
    $('.module-features li').removeClass('checked');
    last.prevAll('li').add(last).addClass('checked');
  }
});
```

```css
li.checked {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="module-group">
  <div class="module-toggle module-toggle--on" data-id="module-1">
    Module 1
  </div>
  <div class="module-toggle module-toggle--on" data-id="module-2">
    Module 2
  </div>
  <div class="module-toggle module-toggle--on" data-id="module-3">
    Module 3
  </div>
  <div class="module-features">
    <ul>
      <li class="module-1">Module 1 feature</li>
      <li class="module-1">Module 1 feature</li>
      <li class="module-1">Module 1 feature</li>
      <li class="module-2">Module 2 feature</li>
      <li class="module-2">Module 2 feature</li>
      <li class="module-2">Module 2 feature</li>
      <li class="module-3">Module 3 feature</li>
      <li class="module-3">Module 3 feature</li>
      <li class="module-3">Module 3 feature</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```